# How to click the buttons without element id

Tags: angularjs

Im using protractor for e2e testing.I want to click the buttons

Comment: @vignesh, please edit the question and add the code there - not in comments

Comment: Open the browser console and try to select the same element using the selector you have used, see if it works. If not tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're not using the Protractor API, but the driver directly? Selecting by ng-click might not be the best approach here as well (good practice seems to be selecting based on page structure, not mechanics), I would recommend you to investigate if you can't simply use [by.buttonText](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/455):

```
element(by.buttonText('Place Order'));
```

EDIT: Looking at the way the selector is made, the above will not work - please note **by.buttonText will only match**:

- button
- input type="button"
- input type="submit"

I'm keeping this for anyone who might need this in the future.

If that will not work, maybe you could at least select it by class, e.g. inside a parent? For example:

```
element(by.css('.btn-wrapper > .btn:nth-child(2)'));
```

Also, consider adding a separate class/id for the button, it might be useful later anyway.

Last remark, if you have a large page to test, consider using [page objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) instead of selecting same stuff in separate steps. This way, instead of writing the selector, you'll have a nice, maintainable object, that you can use like:

```
myPage.placeOrderButton().click();
```

Just something to consider.

Comment: Yes, it might not work in this case. Have you tried any of the next approaches I suggested?

Comment: Great answer, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Place order button:

```
$('[ng-if*="checkout"]').click();
```

Cancel button:

```
$('[ui-sref=​"main.store.featured"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="ctrl.placeOrder()"]')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest and the most readable approach here would be to *locate the element by text*:

```
element(by.xpath('//div[. = "Place Order"]'));
```

You may just need to add a [wait for element to become visible](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    placeOrder = element(by.xpath('//div[. = "Place Order"]'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(placeOrder), 5000);
placeOrder.click();
```

Comment: I think because of the way this "button" is made, the selector will actually not match it. I'd say the best approach would be to change the html so it is matched by any of these:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/455/files#diff-89f02ac1eed840a7f24ba7f0c2411178R376

Comment: @wap300 oh, yeah, good point, it's the `div` element. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I found an article where someone was having issues clicking on a div. It seems a bit much for just clicking on a div but I figured the link could help you out

https://adventuresintesting.wordpress.com/tag/protractor-doesnt-click-div/